# How to use a "section image" addable by a user?

Tags: plone

I need to setup a "section image" addable by a user.
The customer wants a different image for every folder placed in the top of the site.
These images can be added/edited by portal user.

Usually I add collective.contentleadimage to the instance. Then I create a new viewlet customizing the contentleadimage code using the aq_parent to have a "traversal way" for folders without a own "section image". In this way all the first-level folders can have a "section image" and the second one a "section image" inherited by the parent folder.

Is there a better way?

Vito

Answer (score 1):

The "traversal way", as you call it, is the simplest option if you need that the image is modifiable by the customer.

Another option could be to rely on the portal_registry:

- add an image anywhere you like
- add an entry in the registry where you specify the location of the image for a specific section